# Shared Django contact form across different views

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I could have sworn this was working in the past, but apparently I didn't test as well as I should have.  I have a form that allows a user to request information on a particular real estate listing.  There are four (4) separate views, one to show all and the other three simply filter the list by attribute, i.e. Leasing, Real Estate Only, etc..

The form works like it should in the view to list objects.all() and I thought I could just call the form_class in my other views, but when I am on a page that is filtered, the form doesn't work...no error message in browser or anything, the email just never reaches our inbox.

If you can take a look at my views below and provide some feedback, I would be very grateful and please let me know if you need to see anythign else.  Thank you.

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.template import Context
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Listing
from .forms import ContactForm


def listing_list(request):
    listings = Listing.objects.all().order_by('listing_order')
    form_class = ContactForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = request.POST.get('contact_name', '')
            contact_phone = request.POST.get('contact_phone', '')
            contact_email = request.POST.get('contact_email', '')
            contact_listing = request.POST.get('contact_listing', '')
            form_content = request.POST.get('content', '')

            # Email the profile with the
            # contact information
            template = get_template('contact_template.txt')
            context = Context({
                'contact_name': contact_name,
                'contact_phone': contact_phone,
                'contact_email': contact_email,
                'contact_listing': contact_listing,
                'form_content': form_content,
            })
            content = template.render(context)

            email = EmailMessage("Form Submission from Listings Page", content, contact_email,
                                 ['to1@emailaddress.com', 'to2@emailaddress.com'], ['bcc@emailaddress.com'])

            email.send()

            return redirect('listing_list')
    return render(request, 'listing/listing_list.html', {'listings': listings, 'form': form_class})


def full_service(request):
    listings = Listing.objects.filter(location_type='FULL_SERVICE').order_by('listing_order')
    form_class = ContactForm
    return render(request, 'listing/listing_list.html', {'listings': listings, 'form': form_class})


def quick_serve(request):
    listings = Listing.objects.filter(location_type='QUICK_SERVE').order_by('listing_order')
    form_class = ContactForm
    return render(request, 'listing/listing_list.html', {'listings': listings, 'form': form_class})


def with_real(request):
    listings = Listing.objects.filter(location_type='WITH_REAL').order_by('listing_order')
    form_class = ContactForm
    return render(request, 'listing/listing_list.html', {'listings': listings, 'form': form_class})
```

Comment: well in the other 3 views you don't have the form.is_valid whole block which actually processes the form and sends the email... or I'm I missing something? just make it as mixin and include it to each view. Also this whole design is just bad, you have to copy the code to every single view, with just different `location_type`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick feedback and for the reference to use mixins.  Yes, I shamefully place my dirty code up here for everyone to see :) I know it can be much much better, but I am still hacking my way through learning Python/Django and will refractor as I go along.  Thank you.

Comment: I generally use Class-Based views, so I used mixin as it was the first thing that popped in my mind, but you can you normal functions as views, but just make it all one function really with parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#basic-forms) (and [some](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/email/#send-mail) [neat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string) Django [shortcuts](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#accessing-clean-data)) to the rescue:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.views import generic
from django.template import render_to_string


class ContactFormView(generic.FormView):
    form_class = ContactForm
    template_name = 'listing/listing_list.html'
    success_url = 'listings'
    location_type = None

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ContactFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['listings'] = (Listing.objects
                               .filter(location_type=self.location_type)
                               .order_by('listing_order'))
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        message = render_to_string('contact_template.txt', form.cleaned_data)
        send_mail('Form Submission from Listings Page', message,
                  form.cleaned_data['contact_email'])
        return super(ContactFormView, self).form_valid(form)


class FullService(ContactFormView):
    location_type='FULL_SERVICE'


class QuickServe(ContactFormView):
    location_type='QUICK_SERVE'
```

Comment: Wow, this is so much cleaner than what I had.... Thanks for the direct links as well to the shortcuts and render_to_string.  I am not using send_mail, so I'll need to refractor back to using SendGrid, but that shouldn't be too difficult. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, you don't have to change anything if you're using Sendgrid, just add a backend to your project: https://github.com/elbuo8/sendgrid-django